# Spring roo 1.2 how to add finder to repository layer

Tags: spring-roo

I created an entity with fields

```
entity jpa --class ~.domain.Account
field string --fieldName email
field string --fieldName password
```

When I created a repository

repository jpa --interface ~.repositories.AccountRepository --entity ~.domain.Account

I want to add a finder to the repository, is there a similar way to add a finder like to add finders in entity?

```
finder add findAccountsByEmail
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finders are only available for active record entities. To generate the query using repositories create a new method in the repository class, decorate it with the @Query annotation and use JPQL to write the query. Your example would be:

```
@Query("select a from Account as a where a.email = :email")
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
List<Account> findAccountsByEmail(@Param("email") String email)
```

Comment: I tried to add List<Account> findByEmail(String email) in the roo repository interface class public interface AccountRepository, and it works need to add any annotation, or any query, just one line

Comment: @CharlieWu I think it works because dynamic finders are baked into spring data jpa (which is used by roo) see this: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/ROO-2694. This is just for context for people who stumble upon this q&a